# Selecting columns equal to a substring in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### My dataframe looks like this

1. clients4.google.com
2. m.facebook.com
3. static.ak.fbcdn.net
4. static.ak.fbcdn.net
5. static.ak.fbcdn.net

I want to select all the rows where the substring fb is available.
In pandas dataframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `StringMethods.contains`:

```
>>> df = pd.read_clipboard(header=None)
>>> df[df[0].str.contains('fb')]
                     0
2  static.ak.fbcdn.net
3  static.ak.fbcdn.net
4  static.ak.fbcdn.net
```